# JQuery empty input not working with .val('');

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a function that works in my JQuery autocomplete.

The function itself seems to work, but when selecting from autocomplete list, the line to empty the input is not working.

I re-created the issue here:

http://jsfiddle.net/bv8nr2gp/1/

Everything works, except the line `$('#' + x).val('');`

**UPDATE**

I've updated the fiddle to include the missing elements.

If you enter a value in the input field and click Add it works. The value is added to the textarea and span and then removed from the input.

If you enter "one" or "two" in the input and choose it from the autocomplete list, it works apart from clearing the input

Comment: The elements with partial id like `_display` and `_add` seems to be missing in your jsfiddle. Please include those and explain in detail how we can test that it's not working

Comment: See update, just added it to the fiddle and added a further explanation

Comment: Please include the code in a snippet in the question, not relying on third-party sites.

Comment: Your issue is that you're clearing the input before the autocomplete has completed.  So it goes: auto-complete:select event, your add function:clear input, auto-complete:set input to selected value.   You can confirm this by adding a setTimeout around the .val('') http://jsfiddle.net/dgxk23b6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're clearing the input before the autocomplete has completed.

From [jquery-ui](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) (with emphasis):

> **select( event, ui )**
>
> Triggered when an item is selected from the menu.
>  *The default action is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected item*.
> **Cancelling this event prevents the value from being updated**, but does not prevent the menu from closing.

The process is:

- auto-complete `select` event
- which calls your `add` function which clears the input
- auto-complete then sets the input to the selected value as part of the autocomplete process

You can cancel the autocomplete `select` so that it doesn't update the input:

```
    select: function(event, ui) {
      addEmailContact(this.id, ui.item.value);
      event.preventDefault();
    }
```